# Extract all Change Packages for all the files in a PTC project

Tags: mks-integrity

I am trying to get a list of all the change packages used to update all the files in a PTC project. I used the following command:

```
si viewproject --recurse --fields=name,creationcpid,cpid,memberrev,indent --project=%Project% --hostname=%Host_name% --port=%port1% -Y
```

But I do not get all the CP used, only the first one. I also tried the command:

```
si rlog --recurse --format="{membername},{memberrev},{revision},{cpid},{author}\n" --noHeaderFormat --project=%Project% --hostname=%Host_name% --port=%port1%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following cli command you will get all change packaged used by current user
    si viewcps

But, `viewcps` accept `--filter=` where you can specify the project

```
si viewcps --hostname=%Host_name% --port=%port1% --filter=project:%Project%
```

This command need to be called recursively for each sub project because will return only change packages from first level in the specified project.

```
Usage: si viewcps options... issue|issue:change package id...; options are:
    --fields=field1[:width1],field2[:width2]... where fieldn can be any of: closeddate,cptype,creationdate,deployrequestid,deployrequeststate,deploytarget,description,id,issue,propagated,propagatedby,siserver,stage,stagingsystem,state,summary,user  The fields to be displayed
    --filter=user:name
             issueid:issue
             state[:closed|:open|:submitted|:accepted|:rejected|:discarded|:commitfailed]
             closeddate:<date>
             creationdate:<date>
             membertype[:member|:subproject]
             member:<expression>
             project:<expression>
             variant:<expression>
             mainline
             description:<expression>
             summary:<expression>
             typemodifier[:committed|:pending]
             type[:add|:addfromarchive|:drop|:import|:exclusivelock|:nonexclusivelock|:renamefrom|:renameto|:movememberfrom|:movememberto|:update|:updatearchive|:updaterevision|:createsubproject|:addsubproject|:addsharedsubproject|:configuresubprojectfrom|:configuresubprojectto|:movesubprojectfrom|:movesubprojectto|:dropsubproject]
             hasissue
             pendingreviewby:name
             acceptedby:name[;<date>]
             rejectedby:name[;<date>]
             cptype[:development|:propagation|:deploy|:staging|:resolution]
             stagingsystem:<expression>
             stage:<expression>
             deploytarget:<expression>
             deployrequeststate[|:cancelled|:cleanedup|:cleaningup|:cleanupfailed|:created|:deployed|:executed|:executing|:packageactionsfailed|:packagecontentfailed|:packagingactions|:packagingcontent|:prepared|:preparing|:queuedonsource|:queuedontarget|:readytodeploy|:readytotransfer|:rollbackfailed|:rolledback|:rollingback|:stopped|:transferfailed|:transferring]
             deployrequestid:<expression>  The filter used to select change packages 
    --height=value  The height in pixels of the windows
    --myReviews  Show the change packages awaiting review by current user
    --query=value  The query used to select change packages 
    --width=value  The width in pixels of the windows
    -x value  The x location in pixels of the window
    -y value  The y location in pixels of the window
    -?  Shows the usage for a command
    --[no]batch  Control batch mode (no user interaction in batch mode)
    --cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory
    -F value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --forceConfirm=[yes|no]  Specify an answer to all confirmation questions
    -g  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --gui  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --hostname=value  Hostname of server
    -N  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --no  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --password=value  Credentials (e.g., password) to login with
    --[no]persist  Control persistence of CLI views
    --port=value  TCP/IP port number of server
    --quiet  Control status display
    --selectionFile=value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --settingsUI=[gui|default]  Control UI for command options
    --status=[none|gui|default]  Control status display
    --usage  Shows the usage for a command
    --user=value  Username to login to server with
    -Y  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
    --yes  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
```